# Where to put [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiapplication

I need some help. I want that my app runs without status bar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

I put this line into appDelegate in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Maybe exist better place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enter the key: `UIStatusBarHidden` in your info plist, make it a boolean value and set it to `YES`. Then your app will start without the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it anywhere you want :-) Preferly where you want to hide it :)

Comment: Yes, but I want that status bar was hidden during all application lifecycle, previous answer - exactly what I searching for. Thank you for your answer :)